# Impact Analysis: Enable Opportunity Teams

Tags: opportunity-teams

We have been using Salesforce for the last 4 years now and we have got lot of customization done and it's working great.

I would like to know if I switch Opportunity teams in production instance now as we have requirement to do so, will there be any impact (negative implications relating to this please).

Answer (score 1):

As you say you've done a lot of customization, the impact of enabling Opportunity teams is something that's impossible for anyone here to advise you on. This is something that you'll want to test in a sandbox with data to see if it affects any of the customization you have in place. That's exactly what purpose of sandboxes are for.

Opportunity teams are a great feature of Salesforce that can be very useful. Off hand, I wouldn't necessarily expect them to affect anything, but I also don't know what you've done in terms of workflow or what relationships you've created. They'll have an impact on the sharing of records since anyone who's on a team will be able to automatically see the Opportunity record. You can’t use opportunity teams for private opportunities, so if they're not already, you'll need to make sharing on Opportunities at least public read or public read/write.

Any Opportunity team member profiles will also need to have at least read access to Opportunity (if they can't view the object, they won't be able to view records for the team they're part of). Alternatively, you can add them to some kind of public group where you can assign them a permission set that allows them to view Opportunity records and only share the specific records for the team they're part of. You can still do Opportunity Splits with Opportunity Teams. If you have existing customization that does that for, I don't know how that might be affected. Again, that's something you'll want to test.

You'll find all of this and more discussed in the [Salesforce Help](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=salesteam_overview.htm&language=en_US).